# What am I doing wrong considering the divs will not scale according to my media query input?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I am at the beginning, doing different tutorials and challenging myself with conquering the fundamentals. I know this might seem lowkey for most people but be gentle, i'm sorta new to this.

I tried using Media Queries 4 for example @media (30em <= width <= 50em ) { ... } but it jsut doesn't work for me (browser compatibility is checked btw) so I went with a classic code writing (which you may see below). Unfortunately my divs will not scale properly, I am clearly missing something like a parent-child not sharing the proper settings but I can't see it. Could you point out my mistake please? All it needs to do is scale the divs if the width is lower than 600, between 601 and 960 and above 961 (obv .px)

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Mobile Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
  }
}

/* Tablet Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .sign-up,
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
/* Desktop Styles */


@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  .page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .feature-1,
  .feature-2,
  .feature-3 {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
  .header {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #5995DA;
  height: 80px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #B2D6FF;
}

.content {
  background-color: #EAEDF0;
  height: 600px;
}

.sign-up {
  background-color: #D6E9FE;
}

.feature-1 {
  background-color: #F5CF8E;
}

.feature-2 {
  background-color: #F09A9D;
}

.feature-3 {
  background-color: #C8C6FA;
}
```

The html is just a bunch of divs with an img src inside them. The output is the same no matter what the size of the browser window is.

Comment: make sure you have added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` this viewport meta tag. and add all your media below the file.

Comment: The meta tag was added but not putting the media queries at the end of the css file was what I was doing wrong. Thank you and laferry for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

@sbrrk is right. And also, you should write your media queries at the very bottom, so they will override other rules of the same specificity

Comment: Thanks, like I said above, the problem was that I put them at the beginning of the document instead of adding them at the end. Rookie mistake but hey that's how I learn. Thank you.